# automorphism group of a matrix algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, automorphism-group

Let $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be the algebra of $n\times n$ matices over $\mathbb{C}$. By Skolem-Noether, all automorphisms of this algebra are inner. What is the group of automorphisms of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: You probably mean as a $\mathbf{C}$-algebra, but it would have been better if explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you said says that the homomorphism from $GL_n(\mathbb C)\to Aut(M_n(\mathbb C))$ is surjective.

Think about what the kernel is and apply the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: The kernel is invertible matrices that commute with all of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$. By Schur's lemma, these are scalars. Therefore $\text{Aut}(M_n(\mathbb{C}))$ is $PGL_n(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: @aaa That's what it seems like to me, although I didn't find it in print while I sanity checked.